# Using babel-eslint caused false no-empty error

Tags: javascript, babeljs, eslint

After adding to the project `babel-plugin-transform-class-properties` and therefore `babel-eslint` as the eslint parser, we all of a sudden got `no-empty` errors on empty blocks that contain only a comment. According to [the docs](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-empty/), this is allowed.

Any ideas?

versions:
eslint: 3.13.1
babel-eslint: 8.2.5

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to eslint 5.0.1 fixed the problem